# problems using backends with molecule simulation

Tags: backend, qiskit

I am trying to hide a simple molecule such as H2 and I get an error that I cannot decipher.

I have this code:

```
molecule = MoleculeInfo(
    symbols=["H", "H"],
    coords=([-0.5, 0.9, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
    multiplicity=1,  #Indicador si hay electrónes desapareados (2S+1) 
    charge=0,
)

driver = PySCFDriver.from_molecule(molecule) #Se crea un driver para realizar cálculos con la estructura de la molécula 

problem = driver.run() #Se ejecuta la estructura del driver 


num_particles = problem.num_particles #Cantidad de electrónes 
num_spatial_orbitals = problem.num_spatial_orbitals #Cantidad de orbitales 

mapper = ParityMapper(num_particles=num_particles) #Mapeo usando Paridad 
qubit_op = mapper.map(problem.second_q_ops()[0]) #Hamiltoniano

from qiskit import IBMQ
IBMQ.update_account()
my_provider = IBMQ.get_provider()
my_provider.backends()
my_provider.get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')

from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import SPSA
import numpy as np


def exact_solver(qubit_op, problem):
    sol = NumPyMinimumEigensolver().compute_minimum_eigenvalue(qubit_op)
    result = problem.interpret(sol)
    return result

result = exact_solver(qubit_op, problem)

optimizer = SPSA(maxiter=100)
var_form = EfficientSU2(qubit_op.num_qubits, entanglement="linear")
vqe = VQE(backend, var_form, optimizer)
vqe_calc = vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(qubit_op) #Ejecuta el VQE
vqe_result = problem.interpret(vqe_calc).total_energies[0].real #Extrae la energía mínima 
print("Exact Result:", result.total_energies)
print("VQE Result:", vqe_result)
```

After running the program, I get an error when I want to use the VQE and the Backend:

```
from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import SPSA
import numpy as np

#Solucionador clásico
def exact_solver(qubit_op, problem):
    sol = NumPyMinimumEigensolver().compute_minimum_eigenvalue(qubit_op)
    result = problem.interpret(sol)
    return result

result = exact_solver(qubit_op, problem)

#Solucionador cuántico 
optimizer = SPSA(maxiter=100)
var_form = EfficientSU2(qubit_op.num_qubits, entanglement="linear")
vqe = VQE(backend, var_form, optimizer)
vqe_calc = vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(qubit_op) #Ejecuta el VQE
vqe_result = problem.interpret(vqe_calc).total_energies[0].real #Extrae la energía mínima 
print("Exact Result:", result.total_energies)
print("VQE Result:", vqe_result)
from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import SPSA
import numpy as np
​
#Solucionador clásico
def exact_solver(qubit_op, problem):
    sol = NumPyMinimumEigensolver().compute_minimum_eigenvalue(qubit_op)
    result = problem.interpret(sol)
    return result
​
result = exact_solver(qubit_op, problem)
​
#Solucionador cuántico 
optimizer = SPSA(maxiter=100)
var_form = EfficientSU2(qubit_op.num_qubits, entanglement="linear")
vqe = VQE(backend, var_form, optimizer)
vqe_calc = vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(qubit_op) #Ejecuta el VQE
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Cell In[18], line 16
    vqe_calc = vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(qubit_op) #Ejecuta el VQE
  File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/algorithms/minimum_eigensolvers/vqe.py:191 in compute_minimum_eigenvalue
    optimizer_result = self.optimizer.minimize(
  File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/algorithms/optimizers/spsa.py:514 in minimize
    get_eta, get_eps = self.calibrate(fun, x0, max_evals_grouped=self._max_evals_grouped)
  File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/algorithms/optimizers/spsa.py:335 in calibrate
    losses = _batch_evaluate(loss, points, max_evals_grouped)
  File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/algorithms/optimizers/spsa.py:748 in _batch_evaluate
    results += _as_list(function(batch))
  File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/algorithms/minimum_eigensolvers/vqe.py:256 in evaluate_energy
    raise AlgorithmError("The primitive job to evaluate the energy failed!") from exc
AlgorithmError: 'The primitive job to evaluate the energy failed!'

Use %tb to get the full traceback.
```

I have tried running the same program but with local simulators with noise and everything works fine. I have also tried it with local simulators without noise, but varying the optimizer and it works. The problem I'm having is when trying to use IBM's online simulators.

Comment: The full trace would have given the original exception which triggered the one you show. Its hard to say from your code. You pass something called `backend` that is not set in the sample. This should be an Estimator - the one from QIskit Runtime if you want to run on remote backends. I would suggest checking out the docs there for examples etc. at https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/ibm-runtime and take a look at Session too.